# "Content Security Policy" problem with sample web viewer app

Tags: bentley-itwin

I'm trying to create a basic app with the following command:
npx create-react-app aleapp4 --template @itwin/web-viewer --scripts-version @bentley/react-scripts

when I open the browser, the viewer does not start for security issues:
"Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript`"

I have tied to modify index.html to add a security content policy, but could not find a solution...

How may I fix ?

Comment: the iTwin.js community is most active on their github discussion page https://github.com/itwin/itwinjs-core/discussions

Comment: You should try to follow the error to see exactly what script in your dependencies is asking for this. I don't believe that the iTwin libraries require this directly, but maybe some other dependency does. I have an iTwin application with a very strict CSP.

Also, it is a bad idea, but you can add 'unsafe-eval' to the 'script-src' directive of your content security policy, if you really want to ignore this. But you likely accidentally open yourself to XSS attacks.

Comment: I get it already in a basic application , just created ; and have already tried to modify content security policy , with a meta tag but     "<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'">" , but had not success ; btw, when I create app I see many warnings , I understand it requires react >= 16 but maybe does not work with react 17 ...

Comment: @MikeMike i have posted same question in github discussion page

Comment: are you forgetting to include a `;` in your Content-Security-Policy? With the correct syntax it should work... Do you have errors in the console?